# Semi-Direct Product Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to prove that if $G \cong N \rtimes H  $ then $N \cap H = \{e\}$.

Is it enough to say that if $a \in N$ and $a \in H$, then in $G$ we have $[a,e_h]$  and $[e_n,a]$ - which contradicts the fact that there should be a unique way of expressing $a \in G$ as a product of an element in $N$ and an element in $H$?

Many thanks for any feedback.

Comment: A good answer to this question requires that you tell us what you use as definition of semi-direct product. Is it internal (a property) or external (a conctruction)?

Answer (score 1):

If $G\cong N\rtimes H$ then we know $ |G|=|N||H|$ but if $|N\cap H|>1$ then $|G|<|H||N|$.
Contradiction.
For infinite case we can take an injective map from $G$ to $N\rtimes H$. To show contradiction.
 Actually defination of semidirect product comes from the case reqd to prove. Not in the reverse process.

Comment: That works in the finite case only.

Comment: @User152715 Why is it ncessarily the case that if $N$ intersect with $H$ is greater than 1 then $|G| < |H||N|$? Sorry, just having a bit of trouble seeing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every element of $G$ can uniquely be written as $(n,h)$ with $n\in N$ and $h\in H$.If $e$ is the identity in $G$ then it is also the identity of $N$ and $H$: $e=e_N=e_H$, so that the elements of $N$ (resp. $H$) can be written as $(n, e_H)$ (resp. $(e_N,h)$. Now $N \cap H$ is the singleton $\{(e_N,e_H)\}=\{e\}$.